# Sum column numbers elements in many arrays

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed

I need to sum the the numbers located in the same column in  an array.

The input is:

```
1: 6.1703
44 3.5 0.3
46 7.3 2.3

2: 6.1932
44 5.29379 2.9
46 1.72261 7.2261

3: 6.5664
45 4.756 5.6
46 1.6 2.5

4: 8.0923
44 1.41 7.6
```

The output should be:

```
1: 6.1703
 10.8 2.6

2: 6.1932
 7.01640 10.1261

3: 6.5664
 6.356 8.1

4: 8.0923
 1.41 7.6
```

Comment: the input comes from a text file or a user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach using `awk -v RS="" -f script data`, where script is the following:

```
{
    s1 = s2 = 0;
    for (i=4; i < NF; i = i + 3) {
        s1 += $i;
        s2 += $(i+1);
    }
    print $1, $2 "\n " s1, s2 "\n";
}
```

This makes use of the fact that the "arrays" are separated by blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
/:/ { if ( NR>1 ) printit() ; print ; two=0 ; three=0 ; next;}
NF > 2 { two+=$2 ; three+=$3 ; next }
{ print ; }
function printit() {  printf " %s %s\n",two,three; }
END { printit() ;}
```

- function `printit` print actual result
- sums are computed on a line with a colon (`:`).
- `END` clause is used for final printing.